# array_multisort inconsistenly returns false

Tags: php, array-multisort

I have a strange scenario where the array_multisort function only returns successfully if the array it's acting on is larger than the previous array it acted successfully on.

I am taking a large set of data, extracting subsets of the data, then sorting the subsets and outputing them. array_multisort works on the first subset which has 10 entries. Then it fails on the next three subsets which have less than 10 entries but succeeds on the fourth subset which has 16 entries. Then it succeeds on a subset with 18 entries but fails on the next 6 subsets which all have less than 18 entries. It goes on like this, only succeeding when the number of entries is greater than the last successful sort.

I've added unset commands for both the arrays after I've output the results thinking that might help.

```
        for($k=0; $k<$num_category_skaters; $k++) 
            {
                $skater_sort[$k][FirstName] = $category_skaters[$k][FirstName];
                $skater_sort[$k][LastName] = $category_skaters[$k][LastName];
                $skater_sort[$k][Gender] = $category_skaters[$k][Gender];
                $skater_sort[$k][PartnerFirstName] = $category_skaters[$k][PartnerFirstName];
                $skater_sort[$k][PartnerLastName] = $category_skaters[$k][PartnerLastName];
            }

//print_r($skater_sort);

    // Obtain a list of columns
        foreach ($skater_sort as $key => $row) 
            {
            $FirstName[$key]  = $row['FirstName'];
            $LastName[$key] = $row['LastName'];
            $PartnerFirstName[$key]  = $row['PartnerFirstName'];
            $PartnerLastName[$key] = $row['PartnerLastName'];
            $BirthDate[$key] = $row['BirthDate'];
            $Gender[$key] = $row['Gender'];
            // now sort the columns
            }
            $error=array_multisort($LastName, SORT_ASC, $FirstName, SORT_ASC, $PartnerFirstName, SORT_ASC, $PartnerLastName, SORT_ASC, $Gender, SORT_ASC, $skater_sort);
```

Any guidance woudl be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: This question is off-topic: no repro.  We don't have a [mcve] here.  Of course, PHP's `array_multisort()` REQUIRES that all array parameters have the exact same size, so this question is very unclear.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I resolved the problem but I really don't know the cause of the behaviour. The code that followed the array_multisort command went through the array with a for loop and echoed the array data to the screen. When I took that code and moved it to a function and called the function, the array_multisort worked fine. This makes no sense to me since the display code was following the multisort but at least the issue is resolved.